# Is there anything from the standard library or boost that facilitates conditionally executing a function?

Tags: c++, boost, std

I am refactoring a function with too many if-else's, something like the following but more complicated. Some major characteristics of this function are:

1. It bails out early for many pre-conditions (e.g., `condition1()` and `condition2()`).
2. It only does some meaningful stuff on very specific scenarios (e.g., `doA()` and `doB()`). (Oh yeah, the beauty of temporary bug fixing!)
3. Some pre-conditions may or may not be independent of additional conditions (e.g., `condition3/4/5/6()`).

```cpp
retT foo() { // total complexity count = 6
    if (!condition1()) { // complexity +1
        return retT{};
    }

    if (!condition2()) { // complexity +1
        return retT{};
    }

    if (condition3()) { // complexity +1
        if (condition4() || condition5()) { // complexity +2
            return doA();
        }
        else if (condition6()) { // complexity +1
            return doB();
        }
    }

    return retT{};
}
```

The goal is to call out those actual works on their precise conditions rather than leaving them vulnerable to the change of the if-else structure in `foo()`. More specifically, I would like to turn `foo()` into something like this:

```cpp
retT foo() { // total complexity count = 4
    ConditionalCommand<retT> conditionalDoA{doA};
    conditionalDoA.addCondition(condition1());
    conditionalDoA.addCondition(condition2());
    conditionalDoA.addCondition(condition3());
    conditionalDoA.addCondition(condition4() || condition5()); // complexity +1
    
    ConditionalCommand<retT> conditionalDoB{doB};
    conditionalDoB.addCondition(condition1());
    conditionalDoB.addCondition(condition2());
    conditionalDoB.addCondition(condition3());
    conditionalDoB.addCondition(!(condition4() || condition5())); // complexity +2
    conditionalDoB.addCondition(condition6());

    for (auto& do : {conditionalDoA, conditionalDoB}) {
        if (do()) { // complexity +1
            return do.result();
        }
    }

    return retT{};
}
```

This makes the implementation more linear and the conditions for performing a particular work more explicit. I understand that it would be equivalent to just creating a first-level if-clause for each work with all the added conditions listed, but the above code would:

- reduce our internal complexity measurement (if-else, logical operators, and ternary based, as illustrated in the code comments),
- prevent future intrusion into the first-level if-clauses by a new developer, for example, who wants to `doC()` instead of `doA()` if `condition7()` is `true`, and
- allow me to refine each work's conditions independently of those of the other works (recall that some conditions might be depending on each other).

So the question is, is there any existing std or boost utility that does what `ConditionalCommand` does so I don't need to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: You also check several times the same conditions.

Comment: *"reduce our internal complexity measurement"*. It would be *"hide"*, not really "reduce".

Comment: You really think that this proposed syntax is easier to read and understand than the original code?

Comment: Personally I like the original code.  Trying to get the same performance as is will be difficult if not impossible.  If it's "too much code" then maybe refactor it into multiple functions.

Comment: Got to agree, of the two examples I much prefer the original,

Comment: Your points are all legit, especially regarding the performance. However, regarding complexity, it is not entirely "hiding". The reason why we measure complexity in that way I believe has something to do with the shape of the control flow graph. It is not only about how many conditions you check, but also how the checkings interact with each other. With the new code, the checkings are linear.

Comment: You won't like the original if you see the actual code with much more if-else conditions and more levels of nesting.

Comment: Maybe your cyclomatic complexity is really so high that it needs refactoring, and maybe procedural refactoring really isn't workable... I still wouldn't choose your proposal at the moment - it seems to contradict your own requirements. Specifically, dependencies between conditions are not honoured.

Comment: Just to redirect people's attention, the example is oversimplified so please don't fuzz over it. Consider the condition checks very cheap (which is the case) so let's ignore the performance issue for now. Also, the original control flow may even have bugs in them, so consider making it linear an intermediate step to expose the bugs. Back to the original question, is there anything existing in std or boost to do what `ConditionalCommand` does?

Comment: `conjunction(cond1, cond2, cond3, cond4 || cond5)` has less complexity than `cond1 && cond2 && cond3 && (cond4 || cond5)`, but it is not simpler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit: conclusion at the top, frame challenge below.

> Back to the original question, is there anything existing in std or boost to do what `ConditionalCommand` does?

OK, if you're really not worried about the fact that this design violates your own stated requirements, the answer is: **NO**. Nothing does *exactly* this.

However, you could just write something like

```
std::array condA { condition1(), condition2(), condition3(),
                  (condition4() || condition5()) };
if (std::ranges::all_of(condA, std::identity{})) doA();

if (std::ranges::all_of(
    std::initializer_list<bool>{
      condition1(), condition2(), condition3(),
      (condition4() || condition5()),
      condition6()
    },
    std::identity{})
   )
  doB();
```

or whatever takes your fancy. You're only suggesting a very thin convenience layer over this logic.

---

> This makes the implementation more linear

Between perfectly linear control flow and a perfectly linear data structure, I don't really see any advantage either way on this criterion.

> the conditions for performing a particular work more explicit

If by "more explicit" you mean "more declarative", then I guess so. You've hidden everything that is actually going on inside some mystery templates though, so it had better be *very* clear, intuitive and well documented.

> reduce our internal complexity measurement (if-else, logical operators, and ternary based, as illustrated in the code comments),

Your "internal complexity measurement" is, frankly, stupid. If you optimize for a bad objective, you'll get a bad result.

Here you have *very obviously* increased overall complexity, increasing the learning curve for new developers, making the relationship between conditions and their consequences less clear and control flow much harder to debug.

But you've done it in a way that your "internal complexity measurement" chooses to ignore, so it looks like an improvement.

Although I dislike cyclomatic complexity as a broad measure, if yours is genuinely so much higher than shown in the question that refactoring is required - I'd still try just refactoring the procedural code before I considered your proposal.

> prevent future intrusion into the first-level if-clauses by a new developer, for example, who wants to `doC()` instead of `doA()` if `condition7()` is `true`

Just write unit tests for every combination of your 7 conditions (or a single test that runs every permutation) and let your junior developer find out for themselves when the CI server complains about their branch.

You're not helping *them* get less junior by obfuscating your code like this, you're trying to insulate *yourself* from their mistakes in a way that doesn't actually help them improve.

> Also, the original control flow may even have bugs in them

In that case you should definitely be writing test cases *first*! You're talking about refactoring code you don't trust in a way that violates your own stated requirements with no way to validate the result.

> allow me to refine each work's conditions independently of those of the other works (recall that some conditions might be depending on each other).

If you really want a less error-prone way of organizing this, these condition inter-dependencies should be encoded explicitly. At the moment you can still break everything by adding conditions in the wrong order.

Further, you're currently executing *all* conditions *unconditionally* except for the short-circuit evaluation of conditions 4 & 5. Is this even well-defined? Is it guaranteed to remain well-defined?

Still further, you're now evaluating each condition multiple times, once for each possible action.

If you really must encode this in data rather than code, it could be something like an explicit dependency graph (so `condition2` *depends-on* `condition1` and is never executed unless that dependency evaluates to `true`). Then you can have multiple leaf actions attached to the same graph, and don't need any redundant re-evaluations.

To be fair, implementing this is a pain, but at least it satisfies your dependency requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all the others that your attempt is just hiding complexity under a questionably more readable blanked. I find it much more ***un***readable than the original.

I think your only hope is to look at the original code and play [untangle](https://lagged.com/en/g/untangle) with it.

In your simplified example you have more `return` statements than possible returned values, and I bet in the original too, you have *far* more `return`s than possible returned values. So why don't you simply make a map (with pen and paper) of what condition leads to what return value?

Taking your simple example,

- `retT{}` is returned only if `!c1 || !c2 || !c3 || (!c4 && !c5 && !c6)`
- `doA()` is returned only if `c1 && c2 && c3 && (c4 || c5)`
- `doB()` is returned only if `c1 && c2 && c3 && c6`

Notice that the first boolean can be re-written, using [De Morgan laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws), like `!(c1 && c2 && c3 && (c4 || c5 || c6))`.

Follows the observation that the only important booleans are actually these:

```cpp
bool b1 = c1 && c2 && c3;
bool b2 = c4 || c5;
bool b3 = c6;
```

You can then rewrite your logic as

- `doA()` is returned only if `b1 && b2`, call it `p1`
- `doB()` is returned only if `b1 && b3`, call it `p2`
- `retT{}` is returned only if `!(b1 && (b2 || b3))` = `!((b1 && b2) || !(b1 && b3))` = `!(b1 && b2) && !(b1 && b3)` = `!p1 && !p2`

the last sequence of equalities is the verification that all branches indeed lead to a `return` (otherwise the code would be erroneous).

With the above in mind (and on paper) the code can be simplified like this:

```cpp
bool b1 = c1 && c2 && c3;
bool b2 = c4 || c5;
bool b3 = c6;

if (b1) {
  if (b2) {
    return doA();
  }
  if (b3) {
    return doB();
  }
}
return retT{};
```

or, if you are really scared about the time needed to compute the booleans, you can compute than "lazily":

```cpp
bool b1 = c1 && c2 && c3;

if (b1) {
  bool b2 = c4 || c5;
  if (b2) {
    return doA();
  }
  //bool b3 = c6;
  if (/*b3*/c6) {
    return doB();
  }
}
return retT{};
```